# JavaScript code to "exploit" this vulnerability my friend found

Tags: javascript

I need help with an assignment that can show this hidden button that will skip a question (the website is membean) I have installed greasemonkey and tried

```
document.getElementById(“pass”).className = ”visible”;
```

But that didn't work. This is the HTML

```
<input class="hidden" id="pass" onclick="this.origText = this.value;         this.value='Wait...'; that = this; setTimeout(function()         {that.value = that.origText}, 15000);" type="submit" value="Pass" />
```

Can someone help?

Comment: It means you don't have enough activity on the site.. maybe you do now.

Answer (score 2):

Your quotes seem off. Instead of

```
document.getElementById(“pass”).className = ”visible”;
```

try

```
document.getElementById("pass").className = "visible";
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, the 'hidden' class is just setting the css property to `display: none;` or `visibility: hidden`.

You could just remove the 'hidden` class entirely:

```
document.getElementById("pass").className = "";
```

Which would remove the 'hidden' class. Or, you manipulate the css directly:

```
document.getElementById("pass").style.visibility = "visible";
document.getElementById("myDIV").style.display = "block";
```

Those options should both work.

Or, you could just use the dev console in Chrome to unhide the element and click on it.

Or, you could just not unhide the button using "onclick" exploits and take the SATs seriously.